How to update multiple values of a dict in a row with postgresql
I have a table with two columns and the following data. I'm stuck with this table's structure and have no possibility of revamping it since the company has grown significantly and a lot of features depend on that particular format.
EDIT: "value1" is actually 5-level deep in the real table. The real path to "value1" looks like "uuidX"->"ONE"->"TWO"->"THREE"->"FOUR"->"value1".



id (long)
steps (jsonb)




1
{"uuid1": {"value1":[10]}, "uuid2": {"value45":1}}


2
{"uuid3": {"value1":[1]}, "uuid4": {"value1":[3]}



And I want to update these data to get the following table (transforming the array in "value1" to a scalar):



id (long)
steps (jsonb)




1
{"uuid1": {"value1":10}, "uuid2": {"value45":1}}


2
{"uuid3": {"value1":1}, "uuid4": {"value1":3}



The problem is with the uuid key of the top-level dictionary. I can't manage to get the expected result when there are multiple "value1" key in a single row.
Thanks to this question, I got the following request:
with s AS (
    SELECT
        a.id,
        ARRAY[key,'value1'] as path,
        value#>'{value1}'->0 as value
    FROM a, jsonb_each(steps)
    WHERE (value->'value1') IS NOT NULL
      AND value#>'{value1}'->0 IS NOT NULL
)
UPDATE a
SET steps = jsonb_set(a.steps, s.path, s.value)
FROM s
WHERE s.id = a.id;

The s table has 3 rows:



id (long)
path
value




1
"uuid1"
10


2
"uuid3"
1


2
"uuid4"
3



However, this only modifies one record at a time. How can I modify my request so that all "value1" nested key in a single row get updated?
Thank you for your time.

If you want to use PostgreSQL, you should model according to First Normal Form. Otherwise use any NoSQL database.

@TheImpaler the issue is that it is not my database. I have no mean of revamping the entire project. I'm just here to do a quick change :)

The query works but it looks like a monster.. To avoid such queries you need to normalize your DB as it was mentioned in the comment section.
Demo
Main idea:

Detect pairs with value1 value which need to be updated.
Detect keys from the pairs from step 1.
Construct updated jsonb pieces using previously detected key-value pairs.
Subtract from the original jsonb field keys which need to be updated, so we get 'immutable' part of the original jsonb.
Construct final jsonb: merge updated jsonb pieces with immutable ones (step 3 and 4 respectively).

The caveat is that the order of the key-value pairs in the final jsonb may differ from the original.
-- final query
with tmp as (
  with
  -- jsonb presented as key-value pairs with 'value1'
  disjointed_data as (select
        test_data.id,
        key as key,
        value#>'{value1}'->0 as value
    from test_data, jsonb_each(steps)
    where (value->'value1') is not null and value#>'{value1}'->0 is not null
  ),
  -- keys with 'value1' to update
  aggr_keys as (select
        test_data.id,
        array_agg(key) as keys
    from test_data, jsonb_each(steps)
    where (value->'value1') is not null and value#>'{value1}'->0 is not null
  group by test_data.id
  ),
  -- prefinal jsonb parts to aggregate
  prefinal_jsonb_parts as (select
      dd.id,
      jsonb_build_object(dd.key, json_build_object('value1', dd.value)) as upd_part
    from disjointed_data as dd
    
    union

    select test_data.id, 
      steps - aggr_keys.keys as unchanged_part
    from test_data
    join aggr_keys on aggr_keys.id = test_data.id
  )
select pp.id, jsonb_object_agg(key, value) as result_jsonb
from prefinal_jsonb_parts as pp, jsonb_each(pp.upd_part)
group by pp.id
order by pp.id -- not necessary operation
)
update test_data
set steps = result_jsonb
from tmp
where test_data.id = tmp.id;


Using two subqueries with jsonb_each:
select t.id, (select jsonb_object_agg(k.key, (select jsonb_object_agg(k1.key, 
     case when jsonb_typeof(k1.value) = 'array' 
       then (k1.value ->> 0)::jsonb else k1.value::jsonb end) 
   from jsonb_each(k.value) k1)) 
  from jsonb_each(t.steps) k) 
from tbl t

See fiddle
Update: a solution to handle n levels deep is to use regexp_replace with a recursive cte:
with recursive cte(id, steps) as (
   select t.id, t.steps::text from tbl t
   union all
   select c.id, regexp_replace(c.steps, '(?<="value\d+"\:)\s*\[(\d+)\]', '\1')
   from cte c where regexp_substr(c.steps, '(?<="value\d+"\:)\s*\[\d+\]') is not null
)
select c.id, c.steps::jsonb from cte c 
where regexp_substr(c.steps, '(?<="value\d+"\:)\s*\[\d+\]') is null

See fiddle

hello, thank you for your help ! Is the only way to generalize it to x-level deep just chaining the subqueries together ?

@MarcoBresson You can certainly chain the subqueries together, but it would most likely become very onerous :) I have added an update which uses regular expressions to recursively replace instances of arrays containing a single element associated with a key matching the pattern "valueX". This will work at any depth.

First flatten while converting arrays to values (the fl subquery) and then re-aggregate.
select id, jsonb_object_agg(l1k, jsonb_build_object(l2k, v)) steps
from 
(
 select id, l1.key l1k, l2.key l2k, 
    case when jsonb_typeof(l2.value)='array' then l2.value[0] else l2.value end v 
 from the_table,
 lateral jsonb_each(steps) l1,
 lateral jsonb_each(l1.value) l2
) fl
group by id;

DB-fiddle

thank you for your answer! Your query is very elegant indeed. In my case, "value1" is 5-level deep and I'm afraid that the final query is still gonna be a monster (tho it's queries I would only generate once with a piece of code that does it for me). I'm gonna edit my OG question to better reflect that. Anyway, I'll explore this request! Thank you very much for your help
